# Issue invoking firefox 51.0.1 with Selenium 3.0.1 on Eclipse Neon

Tags: firefox, selenium3

I have issue with opening the URL on Firefox Browser using Selenium 3.0.1 on Firefox 51.0.1

Environment :

> ```
> MAC Sierra
> Eclipse Neon.2
> Firefox 51.0.1
> ```

I receive below exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console
>   output:" error. Snapshot is also attached.

This is my code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class JavaScriptExecutor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "/Users/saraddhungel/Downloads/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");
}[error message][1]
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your class name as Selenium already have predefined interface so you can use this name as your class name
2. use following code for set properties

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drive_path//geckodriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   ```
3. use complete url with `http` or `https`

Comment: I did change the class name however still receiving error. I receive new error. Please see below :                                                                                           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/DaemonExecutor
 at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.<init>(UnixProcess.java:52)
 at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:47)

Comment: Please make sure you have downloaded all required jar files